# iPhoto "passworded folder" mechanism

Tags: photos.app

In iPhoto, I have all pictures I've ever taken, or opened from my email.

It includes, for example, pictures of my gf showing me the underwear she is hesitating to buy, or anything else I might not be willing to show while streaming through the pics with a few friends.

Is there any way I could, without entirely deleting these pictures, turn some security on, as if they were in a passworded folder?

It seems some privacy/security feature must be available in such a massively used software, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to have **multiple iPhoto libraries**, and keep one on an **encrypted Disk Image**.

1. Create an encrypted disk image in Disk Utility, or some other utility. This might be a good use for [Knox](https://agilebits.com/knox), which lets you easily create an encrypted disk image and unlock it and mount it when you want.
2. When you open iPhoto, hold down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Option) key and you will be asked to select which iPhoto library you want to open.

Comment: Interesting solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to password protect individual photos or albums from someone who has access to your account.

That said, if you are going to be the one scrolling through the photos, you can right-click on any image and choose "Hide". Then, in the View menu, unselect Hidden Photos. (Keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). This will prevent the photos from appearing, but anyone with access to the mouse or keyboard can unhide the photos.

Comment: Thanks Tubedogg. I'm going to test Sam Rae's solution, but yours is a simpler  quickfix in the meantime.